# Firebase database isn't starting

Tags: node.js, firebase-admin

I am a newbie in JavaScript. Recently I have installed firebase admin and kept the code in global scope, database.js. Like this.

```
import app from 'firebase-admin';
import firebase_key from './firebase_key.js';
app.initializeApp({
    credential: app.credential.cert(firebase_key),
    databaseURL: "https://study-boss-681fa-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com"
});
console.log('database started');
export default app.database();
```

Now I want to access this database from my service class. My serice class is

```
import { getDatabase} from "firebase-admin/database";
const database = getDatabase();
```

This service class code is throwing the following error.
**FirebaseAppError: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just using `getDatabase()` directly then there's a high chance that it's being access before your `initializeApp` is executed. I would recommend initializing all Firebase services in a single file and importing them wherever required as shown below:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase-admin/database';

import firebase_key from './firebase_key.js';

const app = initializeApp({
    credential: app.credential.cert(firebase_key),
    databaseURL: "https://study-boss-681fa-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com"
});

const database = getDatabase(app);
console.log('database started');

export { database };
```

Now you can `import { database } from "..path/to/firebase.js"` wherever required.

Comment: Shouldn't the database initialize every time when 
    import { database } from "..path/to/firebase.js"
 is called?

Comment: @SaaDIbneJamal I didn't get you. You would import the database only once anywhere right? Also there'll be only 1 instance of DB so that should not be an issue.

Comment: Thank you, sir. It is resolved.